# Cloudformation Parameter map and using !join to join API Gateway uri

Tags: mapping, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am using mapping to map API Gateway uri wrt region and environment. In policy using !FindInMap[KensisAPIMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", !Ref envname]]]

While creating stack using below template snippet I am getting **"Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined."** Error

```
Mappings: 
 DataAPIMap: 
  us-west-2: 
    DevOne: "09lvg5kd1l/*/PUT/*/*/*/v2"
    TestOne: "default"
  eu-central-1: 
    devTwo: "sixv6a77sg/*/PUT/*/*/*/v2"
    TestTwo: "default" 
 KensisAPIMap: 
  us-west-2: 
    devOne:
        - !Join ["", [!Sub '${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:we4x5ulbsl/*/PUT/s']]
  eu-central-1: 
    devTwo: 
        - !Join ["", [!Sub 'us-west-2', !Ref KensisActId ,':we4x5ulbsl/*/PUT/s']]
Resources:
   ----
```

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly are you using `FindInMap`? Its not shown in your question.

Comment: I am using that in policy


PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:          
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke'
            Resource:              
              - !Join ["", [!Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:',!FindInMap [TAAccountAPIMap, !Ref "AWS::Region", !Ref vpcname]]]

Answer (score 0):

In  us-west-2: devOne, it seems like you don't need Join at all.
So:

```
KensisAPIMap: 
  us-west-2: 
    devOne: !Sub '${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:we4x5ulbsl/*/PUT/s'
```

With regards to devTwo try smth like this? Be careful with indentation

```
devTwo: 
    Fn::Join: 
     - ""
     - - us-west-2 
       - !Ref KensisActId 
       - :we4x5ulbsl/*/PUT/s
```